# Acquire model instance as view parameter instead of model id

Tags: django, laravel

In laravel, it's possible to have access to entire models with type-hinting the parameter with a model class. for example:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', function(\App\Post $post) {
    /* 
       $post is now the model with pk in url and
       if the pk is wrong it throws an 404 automatically
    */
});
```

How is that possible in django? (with functions as view)

```
def posts(request, post_id):
    post = get_model_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    # ...
```

The second line is completely boilerplate and so much repeated in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [custom path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for that. We can for example make model path converter:

```
# app/converters.py

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls.converters import IntConverter

class ModelConverter(IntConverter):
    model = None

    def to_python(self, value):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=super().to_python(value))

    def to_url(self, value):
        if instanceof(value, int):
            return str(value)
        return str(value.pk)

def model_converter(model):
    class Converter(ModelConverter):
        model = model
    return Converter
```

Then in your `urls.py` you can make model converters and register these once:

```
# app/urls.py

from app.converters import model_converter
from app import views
from app.models import Post
from django.urls import path, register_converter

register_converter(model_converter(Post), 'post')

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/<post:post>', views.post, name='post'),
    # …
]
```

Then in the view, you obtain the `Post` object (given a post for that primary key exists) through the `post` parameter:

```
app/views.py

def post(request, post):
    # post is here a Post object
    # …
```

In your template, you can then just pass the `Post` object in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url), so:

```
<a href="{% url 'post' mypostobject %}">
```

Comment: It's great but the amount of code required to make it possible is a lot. The entire point of my question was to eliminate that one extra line of get_object_or_404. Why Django didn't make it possible by only type-hinting?

Comment: Your code has a small bug, `django.urls.converters` should be imported instead of 'url'. I cannot edit it. isinstance should be used. and in model_converter those two variables can't have the same name

Comment: @NajafiMH: I think Python library often do no take type hints into account, so it is more the "ecosystem" of Python. But it might be worth that there is a Django library to make the use of models in urls more convenient. Perhaps if I find some time, I will try to export this into a more usable package. Fixed the bug.